# How do I find if string has at least one character using regex?

Tags: java, regex

Examples:

1. "1 name": Should say it has characters
2. "10,000": OK
3. "na123me": Should say it has characters
4. "na 123, 000": Should say it has characters

Comment: What do you mean by alphabets?  Only alphabetic characters? /[a-zA-Z]*/

Comment: please clarify your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "find if string has alphabets"? Do you wanto to know if the string has some alphabetic character?

Comment: To clarify, you want to ask if a string has **at least** one alphabetic character?

Comment: As per your update, how about characters like %, #, !, some hebrew/chinese/japanese, etc? You want to restrict to **numbers** only? You want a valid and parseable number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression you want is `[a-zA-Z]`, but you need to use the `find()` method.

This page will let you test regular expressions against input.

http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm

Answer (score 12):

```
public class HasCharacters  {
    public static void main( String [] args ){
        if( args[0].matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*")){
            System.out.println( "Has characters ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ok");   
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
$java HasCharacters "1 name" 
Has characters 
$java HasCharacters "10,000"
Ok
$java HasCharacters "na123me"
Has characters 
$java HasCharacters "na 123, 000" 
Has characters
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Java regexes are by default bounded by `^` and `$`. Test with `1name` yourself.

Comment: It fails for the first example

Answer (score 6):

```
 public static void main(String[] args)

 {
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z]*)+$");
     Matcher m = p.matcher("1 name");
     Matcher m1 = p.matcher("10,000");
     Matcher m2 = p.matcher("na123me");
     Matcher m3 = p.matcher("na 123, 000");
     Matcher m4 = p.matcher("13bbbb13jdfgjd43534 fkgdfkgjk34 rktekjg i54 ");

     if (m.matches())
         System.out.println(m.group(1));

     if (m1.matches())
         System.out.println(m1.group(1));

     if(m2.matches())
         System.out.println(m2.group(1));

     if(m3.matches())
         System.out.println(m3.group(1));

     if (m4.matches())
         System.out.println(m4.group(1));
 }
```

The above should match any letter in both lower and upper case. If the regex returns a match, the string has a letter in it.

Result

> 1 name
>
> me
>
> na 123, 000
>
> i54

Statements that contain no letters do not match the expression.

Comment: If it matches, the string has *only* letters (A-Z) in it.

Comment: Should be fixed now. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Regular expressions that begin with '^.*' or end with '.*$' are poorly written.  Why not just use the regular expression '[a-zA-Z]'?

Comment: @David: unlike in PHP, Perl and another languages, Java regexes are **implicitly** bounded by `^` and `$`.

Comment: @BalusC, incorrect!  The `matches()` method uses the whole string, but the `find()` method does not.

Comment: @David: I am not that experienced, how ever just because with Java the ^ and $ are implicitly added, I do not think that they should be left out. Putting in an extra character or two won't harm, but I think it makes the code more understandable.

Comment: @David: yes, in `matches()`, that's also what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

With this line you can check if your string contains only of characters given by the regex (in this case a,b,c,...z and A,B,C,...Z):

```
boolean doesMatch = "your string".matches( "[a-zA-Z]*" );
```

Comment: that regex would match any string that has at least one alphabetic character

Comment: I thought it would match any string that had precisely one alphabetic character, not just at least one. Doesn't it need an asterisk?

Comment: This tests only if there is one character in a string

Comment: With the asterisk, it will also match an empty string.

Comment: This doesn't work. Java regexes are by default bounded by `^` and `$`. Test with `1name` yourself.